# Cloud9 git push -> fatal: Authentication failed

Tags: git, github, cloud9-ide

In [Cloud9](https://c9.io/) whenever I try and push to a github repository with the terminal I get the following error:

```
fatal: Authentication failed
```

I am using

```
git push origin master
```

to push to the repository. I have my ssh key added in github so that is not the problem.
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Probably you cloned your repo into Cloud9. 
You might need to change remote origin from https to SSH otherwise authentication errors will persist.

Use Solution # 2 from [Douglas C. Ayers' Cloud9 FAQ](https://github.com/DouglasCAyers/Cloud9-FAQ/tree/master):

`git remote set-url origin YOUR_REMOTE_SSH_URL`